# Enable button in datalist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datalist, datarow

please be gentle- I am relatively new to C#! There are a few threads on this already but they all mostly seem to have overcomplicated code that I can't get my head around with vague explanations.

I have a datalist, fed by a SQL database, that will act as a comments section. I want to enable a button to edit comments if the user either created the comment or is an admin but can't seem to figure out how to:

A) Target the button control within the datalist and

B) Enable it for only comments were the user should have the authority to do so

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <br />
            Comment:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("comment") %>' runat="server" ID="commentLabel" /><br />
            Posted on:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("postedDate") %>' runat="server" ID="postedDateLabel" /><br />
            Posted by:
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "user.aspx?user=" + Eval ("userName") %>'><%# Eval("userName") %></asp:HyperLink><br />
    <!-- Comment edit begins ------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            <asp:Button ID="commentEditButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" visible="false"/>

    <!-- Comment edit ends -------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

C#:

```
             conn1.Open();

        String qry1 = "SELECT comments.comment, comments.postedDate, users.userName FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.userId=users.Id WHERE comments.imgId=@Id ORDER BY comments.postedDate DESC";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qry1, conn1);

        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);

        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Request.QueryString["imgid"]);

        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

        //Derp?
        foreach(DataRow row in ds1.Tables)
        {
            Int32 userIdData = Int32.Parse(row["comments.userId"].ToString());
            if (userIdData.Equals(Int32.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString()))) {
                //DataList2. commentEditButton.Visible = true;
            }   
        }

        da1.Fill(ds1);

        DataList2.DataSource = ds1;
        DataList2.DataBind();

        conn1.Close();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: give command argument to your button, and On ItemDatabound do  your stuff

Comment: I appreciate the input but that means nothing to me. Do you have some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself in the end. I missed giving the `DataList` a `DataKeyField` and added an `OnItemCommand` and a `CommandName` to the **Edit** hyperlink.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataKeyField="Id" OnItemCommand="DataList2_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <br />
        Comment:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("comment") %>' runat="server" ID="commentLabel" /><br />
        Posted on:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("postedDate") %>' runat="server" ID="postedDateLabel" /><br />
        Posted by:
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "user.aspx?user=" + Eval ("userName") %>'><%# Eval("userName") %></asp:HyperLink><br />
<!-- Comment edit begins ------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="commentEditButton" runat="server" CommandName="editComment" Visible="false">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
<!-- Comment edit ends -------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Set up the command:

```
 if (e.CommandName == "editComment")
 {
     //Set condition for button visibility etc here
     String editId = userSearchDataList.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
     //do stuff with editId
 }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the item databound event on databind and set your condition to enable the button there

```
   protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound1(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (userIdData.Equals(Int32.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString())))
        {
            Button cmdButton = e.Item.FindControl("commentEditButton") as Button;
            if (cmdButton != null) cmdButton.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I "handle the item databound event on databind?" Thanks!